# Postgres Search Path between connections

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, multi-tenant

I'm a noob to Postgres, and am setting up a multi-tenant database using one schema per tenant.

To target each tenant I need to set search_path accordingly.

I'm worried about accidentally executing something intended for one tenant on another tenant, if the wrong search path is picked up somehow.

I will be executing Functions from .Net code (via NpgSql). The functions will reside in the public schema. Each function will have the search path set inside it, like so:

```sql
BEGIN
 PERFORM set_config('search_path', tenant, true);
...
END
```

Is there any danger, via concurrency or connection pooling, that the search paths for two calls might be shared, for instance if the 'true' parameter was forgotten or set to false.

I really want to be sure that there's no danger of data from one tenant crossing over in to another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the state when you return a connection to the pool.

This is typically done with `DISCARD ALL`.

If all you need is to reset configuration parameters, you should use `RESET ALL`.